# Regularity of differentials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm trying to understand the following statement from Silverman *Arithmetic of elliptic curves*

> Let $C$ be a curve. If $f$ is a regular function in $P\in C$ and $t$ is an uniformizer in $P$ then $df/dt$ is a regular function in $P$.

With $df/dt$ I mean the unique function $g$ such that $df=gdt$. The reference given by Silverman for the proof is a comment following IV.2.1 in Hartshorne *Algebraic Geometry* but it is still not clear to me! Do you have a proof more elightening (and without sheaf if possible?)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you include the comment in Hartshorne you are referring to?

Comment: Is the comment following IV.2.1

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** "Do you have a proof more elightening (and without sheaf if possible?)"

**Answer:** If $C$ is a regular curve over a field $k$ (algebraically closed) and $x \in C$ is a closed point, it follows there is an isomorphism of the stalk of $\Omega^1_C$ at $x$ and the local ring (since $\Omega^1_C$ is a locally trivial sheaf of rank one):

$$\Omega^1_{C,x} \cong \mathcal{O}_{C,x}e_x,$$

where $e_x$ is a"local basis" at $x$. For this reason $f_x$ is a "regular function at $x$".

There is a canonical map (the universal derivation)

$$d_x:\mathcal{O}_{C,x} \rightarrow \Omega^1_{C,x}$$

where $d_x(f)=f_x e_x \in \mathcal{O}_{C,x}e_x$ and $f_x$ is an element of the stalk of $\mathcal{O}_C$ at $x$.  Hence the claim follows from the fact that $\Omega^1_C$ is locally trivial of rank one when $C$ is regular.

If $k$ is arbitrary and $\Omega^1_C$ is locally trivial of rank one a similar argument proves the case: The stalk is free of rank one: $\Omega^1_{C,x} \cong \mathcal{O}_{C,x}e_x$.

**Note:** There are relations between the module of differentials and regularity/smoothness when $k$ is algebraically closed (Hartshorne, Prop. III.10.4). If $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is a morphism of "nonsingular" varieties over $k$ with $n:=dim(X)-dim(Y)$ then $f$ is smooth of relative dimension $n$ iff $\Omega^1_{X/Y}$ is locally trivial of rank $n$. Hence the cotangent sheaf detects smoothness in the case of an algebraically closed field. More generally you should consult the EGA IV - maybe there are some results.

**Example:** If $C:=Spec(k[t])$ it follows $\Omega^1_C \cong k[t]dt$ and the universal derivation is the map

$$d:k[t] \rightarrow k[t]dt$$

defined by $d(f(t)):=f_tdt:=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}dt \in k[t]dt.$
If $f(t)$ is a polynomial it folllows the partial derivative $f_t$ is a polynomial.

**Example:** If $f: X:=Spec(B) \rightarrow S:=Spec(A)$ where $B$ is a finitely generated $A$-algebra and $dim(X)-dim(S):=n$, it follows $f$ is formally smooth iff $\Omega^1_{B/A}$ is locally trivial of rank $n$. Look up "formally smooth" in the litterature. A noetherian local ring $A$ over a field $k$ is formally smooth over $k$ iff $A$ is geometrically regular, ie $A\otimes_k K$ is regular where $K$ is any extension of $k$.

Hence if your curve is geometrically regular over $k$, a similar argument applies: For any function $f \in \mathcal{O}_{C,x}$ it follows $d_x(f)=f_x e_x$ where $f_x \in \mathcal{O}_{C,x}$ is a function regular at $x$.

Comment: Ok it is almost clear but what happens if $k$ is not algebraically closed?

Comment: @cartesio - I do not have a precise reference - look up "formally smooth" in the litterature.